# setting TopologyChangeAware on jdbc voltdb client

Tags: jdbc, hikaricp, voltdb

I am making a jdbc connection to voltdb, how to make this connection **TopologyChangeAware**. over here i am using Hikari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got answer

> For now, the jdbc client does not have a TopologyChangeAware property, but there is  a similar one called *autoreconnect* that we can put into your connection URL.

It is described in the docs here:[usingvoltdb jdbc](https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/ProgLangjdbc.php#Progjdbcconnect)

It looks something like this:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(
 "jdbc:voltdb://svr1:21212,svr2:21212?autoreconnect=true");
```

When set to true, the jdbc client will automatically try to reconnect to any nodes that disconnect until they rejoin the cluster.